# Run a function only on second load of view

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am creating an iOS application which has a login system over a tab bar controller. The tab bar is loaded as the root controller and if the user is not logged in, a login subview fills the screen. Because the first view of the tab bar controller is already loaded, so is `viewWillAppear:`. I use `viewWillAppear:` to reload a table view on every load. The system works great.

However, I want to know how I can run a function (a `void` thing) on just the second load (ie. after the user has logged in), to provide a table view specific for the user rather than loading one on every view - this is why I am not using `viewDidLoad:`, as it only runs once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I have the much better & easy solution rather than taking some variable since the won't retain the last values when we restart our application.

For that you need to use Database but that takes to much of coding.So better to have NSUserDefaults  which is used to store the system preferences.

```
Write this in your viewWillAppear:

if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueforKey:@"key"]==nil)
{
    NSUserDefaults *default = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [default setValue:@"1" forKey:@"key"];
    [default synchronize];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Once you make successful login this value wont change till you make logout");
}

& now just change the value in NSUserDefaults while doing logout.


NSLog(@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForkey:@"key"]); // way to access this system dictionary.
```

For further reference Google for **NSUserDefaults Tutorial**

Hope this solve some sort of problem of urs. :)

Answer (score 1):

add an integer instance variable, increment it on each viewWillAppear and run your function only if your instance variable is bigger than 1

Comment: sorry, fairly new to Objective C coding - how do you do increments?

Comment: if its just an int you can do variable++;

Comment: just used this to give it a test and returns 0 every time int i = 0; int i2 = i++; NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i2]; NSLog(myString);

Comment: sorry, dopey me - i moved the int i; outside of the loader and it worked! thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you keep a counter it will not work because user can open your view many times without logged in. So what should you do this keep the user's session information. When the user logged in fill in this session info otherwise not. Check this info every time when the user wants to open this tab.

Comment: not really the answer I was after. the user cant see anything at all unless they are logged, however the view is still loaded but not accessible.

Comment: im not sure you really understand what I wrote before. the tab bar controller is the root view controller so what ever is first on the tab bar is automatically loaded